# Creating a LocalDate from 3 int's in Java

Tags: java

If I have a start date and finish date which is captured from Scanner like this "enter start year", "enter start month", "enter start day" and "enter end year", "enter end month", "enter end day". How do I combine the int's to create a LocalDate for startDate and endDate? Is this right:

```
    LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse(startYear + "-" + startMonth + "-" + startDay);
```

Comment: Why not `LocalDate.of(startYear, startMonth, startDay)`?

Comment: How about `LocalDate.of(startYear, startMonth, startDay)`? Did you look at the list of factory methods available in `LocalDate` in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)?

Comment: See [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#of(int,int,int)) for the factory method `LocalDate.of​(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)`

Answer (score 3):

What you want is to use the `of` factory method from the `LocalDate` class:

```
    int startMonth = 12;
    int startDay = 3;
    int startYear = 1942;
    LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(startYear, startMonth, startDay);
```